Mapping Appium logs to the execution
When we start appium and then also start running our automation execution, we see a lot of logs appearing the appium window. We would like to capture those logs and display them as part of our report. However, I am not sure how to map the execution to the console logs. We generate a uuid in our executions. Is it possible to set that in the capabilities and when appium print the capabilities, we can start capturing the logs for that particular execution.
Let me know if there are any other better ways for achieving this?
